# Why objdump disassembly don't have .data section?

Tags: linux, memory, nasm

Sorry, if question is too naive but I didn't get why my disassembly don't have that hello world string, or how it's loading that string into memory while executing.

```
section .data
  msg: db "Hello, World!",0xa
  len: equ $-msg


global _start
section .text
  _start:
  mov rax,0x01
  mov rdi,1
  mov rsi,msg
  mov rdx,len
  syscall

  mov rax, 0x3c
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
```

Objdump -d

```
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  401005:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40100a:   48 be 00 20 40 00 00    movabs $0x402000,%rsi
  401011:   00 00 00 
  401014:   ba 0e 00 00 00          mov    $0xe,%edx
  401019:   0f 05                   syscall 
  40101b:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
  401020:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  401025:   0f 05                   syscall
```

If it is moving address of msg string into $rsi then how it decide that address even before executing is this all done by linker? if yes can you give little bit insights?I know each program have there own virtual memory, but is that linker while linking put that string somewhere in memory?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add more details: what is your assembly file, how do you compile and run that? Did you try other disassemblers?

Comment: What made you decide to add `-d` option, which means only do text section?  Are you aware of `man` command?

Comment: Sorry, got it. I completely overthink it.